# Forcing Spring's MBeanExporter to use a particular MBeanServer

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jmx, mbeans

I have a web application running on JBoss 4.2.2. In order to monitor performance I have enabled the internal platform JMX server that ships with Java 5. In other words, I added:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

to JBoss' launch script. This works as expected. However, as a result of this, all MBeans are now registered on the platform MBeanServer. I don't want that, I want them to be registered on JBoss' MBeanServer.

The difficulty lies in the fact that I use Spring to register my managed beans. For this, `MBeanExporter` is used. Thus, I need to tell my `MBeanExporter` to use JBoss' MBeanServer when registering beans. However, the only exposed method in `MBeanExporter` to affect what server is used is `setServer(MBeanServer mBeanServer)`. The problem is that I only know how to get a reference to the correct MBeanServer *programmatically*, and not in Spring's XML, where the `MBeanExporter` is declared.

My options appears to be:

1. Write a subclass to `MBeanExporter`, overriding certain methods, so the correct MBeanServer is loaded
2. Write a `PostBeanProcessor` that finds JBoss' MBeanServer and then calls `setServer`
3. JNDI? Only works if the MBeanServer is exposed in JNDI, and I haven't been able to find it.

What is the most idiomatic way? Am I doing something really silly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the static factory method from the JBoss API to inject the MBeanServer into the MBeanExporter:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="server">
        <bean class="org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator" factory-method="locateJBoss"/>
    </property>
    <!-- Add the rest of your MBeanExporter properties here -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. I have used factory-method before, but I didn't see that it was perfect for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I only know how to
>   get a reference to the correct
>   MBeanServer programmatically

If you can get the reference programmatically, why can't you wire it in through the MBeanExporter#server property?

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it before afterPropertiesSet is called on MBeanExporter. I can accomplish this with a PostBeanProcessor, which is the solution I am leaning towards... but I feel like I am doing something that should be really, really simple in a complicated way.

Comment: Why can't you just set the "server" property with the reference to the proper MBeanServer?

Comment: Well, if I do it programmatically, I need some appropriate place to put the call to setServer. And that must be after Spring creates the bean, but before Spring calls afterPropertiesSet on the bean (because that's when the MBeanServer is used). Ideally I would set it in the XML, but I couldn't find a good way to do that until skaffman showed me how.